# Verification of proof of $\tan(x)+\cot(x)=\csc(x)\sec(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

[image: Click here to See my proof]

So I used to proof tan(x)+cot(x)=csc(x)sec(x)
by derivation from pythagorean identity? 
so Is my proof Right?

Comment: Please, write your proof directly in your post. Shouldn't be too hard to use MathJaX formatting from what I can see.

Comment: [mathjax reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553)

Answer (score 3):

Seems fine, we can combine the division togeher.

From $$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1,$$

divide by $\sin x \cos x$,

$$\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin x \cos x} + \frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin x \cos x} = \frac1{\sin x \cos x},$$

$$\tan x + \cot x = \sec x \operatorname{cosec} x$$

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me. The division by $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ could fail (either of those could be 0), but that only happens where the original expression is undefined anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is quite confused, but contains the things that ought to appear.

You can streamline it:
\begin{align}
\tan x+\cot x
&=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \\
&=\frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{\cos x\sin x} \\
&=\frac{1}{\cos x\sin x} \\
&=\sec x\csc x
\end{align}

Comment: I used my proof in math test, so this is mean my proof right?

Comment: @BrainGreene I’d say so, but it should be laid out more clearly.